# How can I plot this data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have 4 columns: date & time, stage_duration, various_stages, Vehicle_ID. I want  to plot date and time in mins on X-axis and id, stage_duration on Y-axis and fill by various stages on line or bar chart.

Something like this would be good:

[image]

Here is my data:

```
var_events  time_date   event_duration      veh_id
LD  17-06-2018 13:25    6.52                   B33
WL  17-06-2018 13:25    14.52                  B31
TL  17-06-2018 13:26    0.32                   B32
TE  17-06-2018 13:26    4.58                   B13
UL  17-06-2018 13:26    3.45                   B12
WT  17-06-2018 13:26    5.46                   B25
UL  17-06-2018 13:26    1.56                   B17
TL  17-06-2018 13:26    13.6                   B33
SL  17-06-2018 13:26    0.05                   B32
```

Here is a minimal example that creates the plot

```
# load data    
data(presidential)
data(economics)

# events of interest
events <- presidential[-(1:3),]

# strip year from economics and events data frames
economics$year = as.numeric(format(economics$date, format = "%Y")) 

# use dplyr to summarise data by year
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
econonomics_mean <- economics %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_unemployment = mean(unemploy))

# add president terms to summarized data frame as a factor
president <- c(rep(NA,14), rep("Reagan", 8), rep("Bush", 4), rep("Clinton", 8), rep("Bush", 8), rep("Obama", 7))
econonomics_mean$president <- president

# create ggplot
p <- ggplot(data = econonomics_mean, aes(x = year, y = mean_unemployment)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = president)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/3)
```

### Update

This is the output:

```
structure(list(Event_stage = c("SE", "MN", "MN", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "WL", "TE", "TE", "SE", "TE", 
"TE", "WL", "WT", "MN", "WL", "TE", "WL", "WL", "WT", "WL", "LD", 
"WT", "WL", "WT", "WT", "TE", "WL", "LD", "WT", "LD", "MN", "TL", 
"TE", "WL", "TL", "TL", "WT", "TE", "TE", "LD", "WT", "TL", "LD"), 
event_date = structure(c(1529573704, 1529573710, 1529573713, 
1529573724, 1529573855, 1529573874, 1529573880, 1529573895, 1529573906, 
1529573918, 1529573925, 1529573931, 1529573931, 1529573941, 1529573947, 
1529573969, 1529574006, 1529574054, 1529574088, 1529574114, 1529574120, 
1529574123, 1529574134, 1529574137, 1529574148, 1529574163, 1529574164, 
1529574148, 1529574169, 1529574170, 1529574178, 1529574188, 1529574189, 
1529574196, 1529574178, 1529574188, 1529574203, 1529574213, 1529574214, 
1529574214, 1529574215, 1529574227, 1529574231, 1529574242, 1529574244, 
1529574245, 1529574248, 1529574260, 1529574262), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), stage_duration = c(3.78, 3.47, 2.78, 
3.45, 3.32, 4.93, 4.23, 4.22, 3.85, 3.37, 5.88, 5.92, 3.97, 3.7, 
NA, 4.08, 3.05, 0.57, 11.18, 12.08, 2.6, 3.3, 0.23, 0.85, 0.27, 
0.25, 0.82, 10.42, 0.15, 0.43, 1.4, 0.25, 0.7, 0.52, 1.12, 0.45, 
12.87, 12.18, 2.92, 0.57, 14.07, 12.72, 17.12, 4.13, 3.13, 0.25, 
0.33, 18.98, 1.05), veh_id = c("B35", "B05", "B04", "B08", "B14", 
"B13", "B04", "B17", "B41", "B05", "B26", "B08", "B35", "B19a", 
"B10a", "B01a", "B28", "B14", "B14", "B18", "B05", "B37", "B04", 
"B41", "B04", "B19a", "B04", "B17", "B35", "B13", "B35", "B02b", 
"B28", "B13", "B19a", "B41", "B02b", "B04", "B15", "B01a", "B41", 
"B13", "B28", "B27", "B33", "B19a", "B01a", "B19a", "B35")), 
.Names = c("Event_stage", "event_date", "stage_duration", "veh_id"), 
row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: dput your data please

Comment: What does your code presently do, and how does that differ from what you want?

Comment: You load the data sets `presidential` and `economics`  but it is not obvious where those come from.  Is some R package required?

Comment: Hi Aleksandr thanks for replying, I don't know how to dput structure the data...

Comment: Hi Halfer thanks for replying, I lost the code i had written on the laptop(it had some hardware issues, lost the data and code i didn't back-up stored). That's the reason i asking you guys to help me out. A line chart or bar chart showing different stages by duration with different colors by ID on yaxis and  time in mins on x-axis will do the job.

Comment: Hi G5W thanks for replying, Presidential and economics dataset's are in-built datasets in R Cran package.

Comment: @Questnoob: G5W wondered what package. The answer is `ggplot` it seems. Information like this should be in your question, usually in the form of a `library()` call.

Comment: @AkselA thanks for your input.

Comment: @Aleksandr Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: @halfer  Any help is Appreciated

Comment: @G5W Any help is Appreciated

Comment: @AkselA Any help is Appreciated

Comment: I don't know `ggplot` hardly at all either, so not much help there, but the problem seems to be that we don't understand what you want. You have a plot and the code producing that plot, which seems to to fit your needs. What else remains?

Comment: @Questnoob, suppose your data is in df, so dput(df) will give you your data sample. Just copy/paste the output of dput(df) here.

Comment: @Questnoob: your last reply about code to "do the job" appears to be a request for free work. That will not be received well here. If you wrote it before, then you can write it again. People will help if you get stuck.

Comment: @G5W Thanks anyways.

Comment: @AkselA I am trying to plot it but one or the other error pops up, Because I am a newbie to R I am not able to figure out How to Plot this time-series data showing various stages by different colors, the duration of the stage and time and date in intervals of 5 mins by ID....Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Alexsandr Updating it Asap. Thanks Alex.

Comment: @halfer I am trying to plot it but one or the other error pops up, Because I am a newbie to R I am not able to figure out How to Plot this time-series data showing various stages by different colors, the duration of the stage and time and date in intervals of 5 mins by ID....I like that you're upfront about it but i did try to plot by myself i am messing one thing or the other, So just want to see how its done Correctly by an expert. Thanks anyways Halfer.

Comment: @Aleksandr Hi alex, This is the output  2.51666666666667, 2.55, 2.71666666666667, 2.75)), .Names = c("event_date", 
"event_duration", "vehicle_id", "event_state", "hr"), row.names = c(NA, 
-65245L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: dput output should start with: structure(list(. Make sure you copy all of it.

Comment: @Aleksandr Its a huge file alex, so parsed 500 data strings::

Comment: @Aleksandr Hi alex, Updated the output with a sample.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

df = structure(list(Event_stage = c("SE", "MN", "MN", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "WL", "TE", "TE", "SE", "TE", "TE", "WL", "WT", "MN", "WL", "TE", "WL", "WL", "WT", "WL", "LD", "WT", "WL", "WT", "WT", "TE", "WL", "LD", "WT", "LD", "MN", "TL", "TE", "WL", "TL", "TL", "WT", "TE", "TE", "LD", "WT", "TL", "LD" ), event_date = structure(c(1529573704, 1529573710, 1529573713, 1529573724, 1529573855, 1529573874, 1529573880, 1529573895, 1529573906, 1529573918, 1529573925, 1529573931, 1529573931, 1529573941, 1529573947, 1529573969, 1529574006, 1529574054, 1529574088, 1529574114, 1529574120, 1529574123, 1529574134, 1529574137, 1529574148, 1529574163, 1529574164, 1529574148, 1529574169, 1529574170, 1529574178, 1529574188, 1529574189, 1529574196, 1529574178, 1529574188, 1529574203, 1529574213, 1529574214, 1529574214, 1529574215, 1529574227, 1529574231, 1529574242, 1529574244, 1529574245, 1529574248, 1529574260, 1529574262), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), stage_duration = c(3.78, 3.47, 2.78, 3.45, 3.32, 4.93, 4.23, 4.22, 3.85, 3.37, 5.88, 5.92, 3.97, 3.7, NA, 4.08, 3.05, 0.57, 11.18, 12.08, 2.6, 3.3, 0.23, 0.85, 0.27, 0.25, 0.82, 10.42, 0.15, 0.43, 1.4, 0.25, 0.7, 0.52, 1.12, 0.45, 12.87, 12.18, 2.92, 0.57, 14.07, 12.72, 17.12, 4.13, 3.13, 0.25, 0.33, 18.98, 1.05), veh_id = c("B35", "B05", "B04", "B08", "B14", "B13", "B04", "B17", "B41", "B05", "B26", "B08", "B35", "B19a", "B10a", "B01a", "B28", "B14", "B14", "B18", "B05", "B37", "B04", "B41", "B04", "B19a", "B04", "B17", "B35", "B13", "B35", "B02b", "B28", "B13", "B19a", "B41", "B02b", "B04", "B15", "B01a", "B41", "B13", "B28", "B27", "B33", "B19a", "B01a", "B19a", "B35")), .Names = c("Event_stage", "event_date", "stage_duration", "veh_id"), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# create ggplot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = event_date, 
                      y = stage_duration)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Event_stage), size= 3) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/2)+
  facet_wrap(~veh_id, nrow = 4) +
  labs(x = "Event date", y = "Stage duration")
```

[image]

Comment: Alex Just amazing...Thank you so much

Comment: Another thing If i want plot single veh_id in countinous series frame, How do i do it?

Comment: Say you want "B35" data, just filter it out:

ggplot(data = df %>% filter(veh_id == "B35"), 
            aes(x = event_date, 
                y = stage_duration)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Event_stage), size= 6) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/2, size = 1)+
  labs(x = "Event date", y = "Stage duration")

Comment: Thanks you once again Alex, You guys are inspiring me to be active on forums like this to help others, When i acquire decent skills. How to be in touch with you on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Hi alex, If you don't mind How can i choose the date and time in this plot?

Comment: What do you mean choose?

Comment: Hi Alex How are you doing, I mean can it be a horizontal line instead of spikes and a horizontal scrollbar showing timeseries till present date and time?

Comment: Also If Can you help me plot it to be a single horizontal bar changing colors by stage and stage duration?

Comment: Hey Alex if got some time could you take a look at this request?

Comment: Prob you should create a new question and provide some attempts what you tried to accomplish so far.

Comment: Hi Alex, Posted a new question as you suggested..I tried plotting geom_bar and geom_rect but it throws an error stat count not to be used with y aesthetic.

Comment: A continous horizontal line or single Bar  and a horizontal scrollbar showing timeseries till present date and time is what i'm trying to plot... Thank you